# Does Windows XP write crash logs for applications?

Tags: windows-xp, crash, logging

Does Windows XP write crash logs for applications like Mac OS does? Where can I find those logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Microsoft support article: [How to view and manage event logs in Event Viewer in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427)

> In Windows XP, an event is any
>   significant occurrence in the system
>   or in a program that requires users to
>   be notified, or an entry added to a
>   log. The Event Log Service records
>   application, security, and system
>   events in Event Viewer. With the event
>   logs in Event Viewer, you can obtain
>   information about your hardware,
>   software, and system components, and
>   monitor security events on a local or
>   remote computer. Event logs can help
>   you identify and diagnose the source
>   of current system problems, or help
>   you predict potential system problems.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can also be configured to write a memory dump on a blue screen crash too. There's also tools for getting dumps of user mode programs crashing too.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP, you can control if crashes are logged, and where (in a dump file, or in the Event Log).
This and more can be configured in the registry.

See http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/win_xp_logfiles.htm for the details.